# How to Programmatically Change Tabs in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tabs, matlab-figure

I'm currently trying to program a line in my MATLAB source that will change the tabs of my GUI that I've created using uicontrol, uitabgroup, uitab, etc.

What I want is a single line piece of code that will change the currently selected tab of a GUI as shown in this documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/166175-how-to-programmatically-select-a-tab-in-a-uitabgroup

However, despite no errors showing, it doesn't change the tab. I'm currently using MATLAB 2011b and find this concerning since the post was made in almost 2015.

Could anyone direct me in an appropriate direction or know of any resources regarding this issue for older versions of MATLAB?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37448206/5540279) answer. It has an example how to change selected tab in a UI built using GUI Layout Toolbox, which is much better than `uitabgroup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uitab` and `uitabgroup` weren't "officially" documented functions until R2014b so it's no surprise that they may have changed between their introduction in 2004, your version from 2011, and the "official" documentation from 2014.

Accorinding to [Yair's blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tab-panels-uitab-and-relatives/), there were a number of changes to `uitab` and `uitabgroup` over the years, particularly in how to programmatically select a tab. It appears that for your version, setting the `SelectedIndex` (a hidden property) should programmatically select the tab.

```
htabgroup = uitabgroup();
htab1 = uitab(htabgroup, 'Title', 'Tab1');
htab2 = uitab(htabgroup, 'Title', 'Tab2');

set(htabgroup, 'SelectedIndex', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## In modern versions of Matlab

Set the property `SelectedTab` of a `TabGroup` object to the handle of the desired tab.

```
function GoToSomeTabButtonPushed(app, event)

    app.TabGroup.SelectedTab = app.SomeTab;

    % Alternatively, assuming the desired tab is the second:
    app.TabGroup.SelectedTab = app.TabGroup.Children(2);

end
```

See a live example [here](https://drive.matlab.com/sharing/45acb9d6-fdee-4d74-b64a-e3f935143711).